# How to export histogram legends correctly?

Tags: plotting, export, output-formatting, legending, histograms

Found it really hard to export a high resolution `.png` while keeping the legends. Here is the code:

```
Export["3.png", 
 Histogram[{data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 3]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Greenland & Antarctica mass frequency", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Mass(Gt)"}, 
  ChartLegends -> {"Greenland", "Antarctica"}], 
 ImageResolution -> 500]
```

And the exported image is like [image: exported]

How can I correctly format this and export?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue has to do with you using `ImageResolution` instead of `ImageSize`.

I didn't have your original data, so I fabricated some:

```
data = RandomInteger[{100, 1000}, 20]
```

Then ran similar code calling the fake data and using `ImageSize->1000`:

```
Export["4.png", 
 Histogram[data, PlotLabel -> "Greenland & Antarctica mass frequency",
   AxesLabel -> {"Mass(Gt)"}, 
  ChartLegends -> {"Greenland", "Antarctica"}, ImageSize -> 1000]]
```

Here is what I came up with:
[image]

If you want to change the text size you can do so with additional options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to use `ImageSize`, but the output image is kind of blurry, that's why I am using `ImageResolution`

Comment: In my previous answer, I had incorrectly placed the `ImageSize` in the export parameters.  In my corrected example, I placed in the `Histogram` paramaters yielding a better result.  You can make the image as big as you want, but you need to change the parameters for the text (key, axes, label, etc.) to compensate.

Comment: I suggest export as PDF format, if you don't insist using PNG.